# Different Views, Same Action Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Views (Bracket and OtherBracket), they would do the same thing in ActionResult, so I'd like to use the same one.

I tried

```
[Route("/Home/OtherBracket/{registrantID}")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Bracket(string registrantID)
{ etc.... }
```

But I'm getting a 404 when I try to go to /Home/OtherBracket?registrantID=123456

Comment: Well of course you are. The route is `/Home/OtherBracket/123456`, *not* `/Home/OtherBracket?registrantID=123456`.

Comment: Can you add your RouteConfig code so we can check your route setup

Comment: I'm just using the default RouteConfig

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple route attributes

```
[Route("Home/OtherBracket/{registrantID}")]
[Route("Home/Bracket/{registrantID}")]
```

Comment: That didn't work, same 404 message, OtherBracket is one word, not sure if there was confusion with that.

Comment: @cheezheadsrule yea, I assumed it's a regex, but I've tried multiple and it worked.